# Passing isolated scope variable from directive to its controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a directive which is using isolated scope. I am passing it a variable from the view.

**DIRECTIVE**

```
function abcDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: 'abc.html',
        controller: 'ABController as abCtrl',
        scope: {
            dataSent: '='
        }
    }
}
```

**THE VIEW**

```
<div abc-directive data-sent="{some: Object}"></div>
```

Now when I open up the Batarang, I see one object of ABCtrl with all the scope elements. And one object having the `{some: object}`. I want this `{some: object}` to be a part of the ABCtrl. How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. Can you make this in a js fiddle or include your controller code plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [new feature in 1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) that will allow you to specify this via the `bindToController` property on the directive definition.

```
{
  scope: {
     dataSent:'='
  },
  bindToController:true
}
```

Until then, you will have to do it manually, either in the linking function, or inside the directive controller:

```
{
   //Using the link function
   link:function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
      ctrl.dataSent = scope.dataSent;

      scope.$watch('dataSent', function(){
         ctrl.dataSent = scope.dataSent;
      });
   }
}

//Using the controller
var ABCController = function($scope){
   this.dataSent = $scope.dataSent;

   $scope.$watch('dataSent', function(){
      this.dataSent = $scope.dataSent;
   }.bind(this));
}
```